# Android navigation component passing argument with safeArgs and deep link

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a navigation xml for a feature as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_featureB.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/FragmentB">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FragmentB"
        android:name="FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB">
        <deepLink app:uri="App://FragmentB" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

In my `FeatureA` fragment, I do the following -

```
val uri = Uri.parse("App://FragmentB")
findNavController().navigate(uri)
```

I know how to use `safeArgs` without deep link.
How do I pass data to other feature with deep link?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do the following

First add argument in `navigation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_featureB.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/FragmentB">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FragmentB"
        android:name="FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB">
        <argument
            android:name="yourarg"
            android:defaultValue="Argument Default Value"/>
        <deepLink app:uri="App://FragmentB/{yourarg}" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Then you can call it like this

```
val args = Bundle()
args.putString("yourarg", "Argument Value")

val deeplink = findNavController().createDeepLink()
               .setDestination(R.id.FragmentB)
               .setArguments(args)
               .createPendingIntent()
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context, "deeplink")
                .setContentTitle("Deep link with data")
                .setContentText("Deep link with data to Android")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentIntent(deeplink)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
val notificationManager =
                context?.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build())
```

**EDITED**

**Without Notification**

First, add argument in navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_featureB.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/FragmentB">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FragmentB"
        android:name="FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB">
        <argument
            android:name="yourarg"
            android:defaultValue="Argument Default Value"/>
        <deepLink app:uri="App://FragmentB/{yourarg}" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Then you can call it like this

```
val uri = Uri.parse("App://FragmentB/yourarg")
findNavController().navigate(uri)
```

Then you can get the argument with this code

```
val argument = arguments?.getString("yourarg")

// Or with Safe Args

val safeArgs: FragmentBArgs by navArgs()
val yourarg = safeArgs.yourarg
```

References :
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation#9

Comment: Is there no other way? I just want to open a fragment in other feature in the same app and do I need notifications for that?

Comment: please check my updated answer, i have provided the way without using notification

Comment: This helps thanks a lot :) I have accepted the answer. But is there a possibility to use safeArgs with deep links?

Comment: Sure, glad it helped :)
Yes, it is possible to use safeArgs, I have updated the answer again :)

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: This only deals with string data types but in many apps, we need to pass custom objects with a deep link. Is there anything we can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Above answers shows how to works with string data types. But if you want to pass custom objects, safe-args also works well;

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/verification_fragment"
    android:name="com.appname.ui.verification.VerificationFragment"
    android:label="VerificationFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="verificationType"
        android:defaultValue="PHONE"
        app:argType="com.appname.core.model.VerificationType" />
    <deepLink app:uri="android-app://com.appname/verification_fragment?verificationType={verificationType}" />
</fragment>
```

Pass custom attributes to deeplink;

```
            val request = NavDeepLinkRequest.Builder
            .fromUri("android-app://appname/verification_fragment?verificationType=${VerificationType.MAIL}".toUri())
            .build()
        findNavController().navigate(request)
```

Read attributes from destination fragments;

```
private val args: VerificationFragmentArgs by navArgs()

args.verificationType
```

Comment: Nah. this will result "Parcelables don't support default values. Android navigation deeplink argument"

for custom attribute better convert it into JSON first, pass it to URI, than convert it back to object.